# Android Switch Button Get Text

Tags: java, android, button, uiswitch

The question is straightforward enough... Is there a way to get the text off of an android switch button in code? No, I don't mean by checking if the switch control is checked and then just pulling the textOn/textOff text. Reason is, I need to pull the text while the user is dragging the control over to the on/off position. I need a way to pull what is currently be shown because I will be acting on the state change on drag not on checked. I already tried mySwitch.getText(), but it is empty. Any help is appreciated. OR, if you have a solution in determining when the user drags the switch all the way to the on position or the off position. Again, not using the onchecked listener since this is only triggered after the user lifts there finger from the switch control. Just when dragging the switch. Thank you.

Comment: Really? I stated what I needed. If you have a better alternative please, let me know. You guys don't need to down vote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`getTextOn()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#getTextOn()) and [`getTextOff()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#getTextOff()) to get the text. That said, I don't understand why you need these and why you cannot use the `OnCheckedChangedListener` -- `Switch` does not have a "dragging" state, it's a binary state on or off. It's basically a fancy `CheckBox`.

Comment: For my application, I need the user to be able to drag the switch from the off position to the on position and hold it there for a certain amount of time before I kick off another task. I can't have the user just toggle the switch because it requires that the user keeps the switch button pressed otherwise it'll jump back (its a spec that I'm following). I looked into SeekBar since this would offer that kind of control, but the UI isn't there. I need the switch UI and the SeekBar back-end functionality.

Comment: Then `Switch` is not the right component. All the CompoundButton subclasses basically work the same way: they're either checked or unchecked (or on or off in the case of `Switch`). `SeekBar` may not be right for you either, at least not without some extension on your part, because `SeekBar` is meant to allow the user to select some discrete value/position in a range. If you actually need the user to hold the thing down with their finger for some time (why?), you might be better off making a custom view and learning how to do the necessary touch handling.

Comment: OK. Yeah, I'm just following the spec (laid out by the customer). It doesn't help that I'm new to the Android world.Maybe I can pull out the Switch control and modify it so it just includes the callbacks that I need. Do you see any issues with that for future use? I was thinking pulling out the Switch.java code, modifying and adding callbacks, then using it.

Comment: Much of the logic is in private methods. You will not be able to add callbacks in those places by simply extending the class.

Comment: Right, I just seen that... I think I'll extend what I can of the Switch class and then override the methods that I will extend off of. I know I can get access to the private methods and port them over to my application, just sounds like a lot of work for something that should seem simple.